# git blame for files that don't exist in current branch

Tags: git, git-blame

I have a file that exists in branch_A but does not exist in branch_B.

I want to run

```
> git checkout branch_B
> git blame branch_A file
```

However, git complains that I don't have the file locally - which is correct but ignores the fact that I want to blame relative to branch_A. I would expect git blame to check for file existence relative to the desired branch instead of the checked-out branch.

I can trick git blame to do what I want if I run this when on branch B:

```
> touch file
> git blame branch_A file
```

Is there a straightforward way of doing this?

Answer (score 14):

Apparently the way to do this is with:

```
> git blame branch_A -- file
```

instead of

```
> git blame branch_A file
```

Comment: Yes, funny that. It works as expected if the file exist in the current branch. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: On the other hand, `git gui blame` seems to *not* accept `--`.